# Iteratively find and modify a certain element in a set in $\log n$ per iteration

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs

I've looked around and can't find my answer.

I have a set of $n$ numbers. In each iteration I would like to find an arbitrary number and change it. Is it possible to perform each iteration in $\log n$ time?

There are data structures like a min-max heap which allow insertion and deletion in $\log n$ time, but that only allows deletion on the min/max values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve that running time if you use the right data structure.  You might want to look at some other data structures, such as AVL trees, red-black trees, or other similar techniques.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_data_structure, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree,  or your favorite data structures book.